# How can I get the scroll to stop propagating in this jsfiddle example

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

the [jsfiddle in question](http://jsfiddle.net/QU5qj/8/). I want to make it so if you scroll inside the 'c' div it doesn't propagate past the 'b' div and into the 'a'. The problem seems to be that the scroll event doesn't propagate as i'd expect it to. Is there any way to make it behave the way I want it to? I tried the same thing with the click event and that worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scroll` is too high level and isn't directly related to the mouse wheel but to the scrolling of the item.

It works if you use the `mousewheel` event :

```
$('#c').on('mousewheel', function(e){
    $('#console').append('<br />C scrolled!');
});
$('#b').on('mousewheel', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#console').append('<br />B scrolled!');
});
$('#a').on('mousewheel', function(e){
    $('#console').append('<br />A scrolled!');
});
```

You can check here that only "C scrolled" and "B scrolled" are displayed when you scroll with the mouse over C : http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/pvxXJ/

Comment: Fiddle added. Isn't it what you want ? If so in what should it be different for your needs ?

Comment: i checked out your jsfiddle and yeah it does only display c and b scrolled but it still scrolls the 'a' div for some reason.

Comment: Ok, so you want, in fact, to prevent the scrolling of the objects, which is very different from preventing the scroll event propagation : The rendering engine doesn't scroll every objects independently as they receive the scroll event. You can't do it that way at all : you can't make div gliding outside their parent with static (default) positionning, you must change the css.

Comment: yeah. any idea or documentatino about how I might do that? I will mark your answer as it's the right one for what I asked in the OP. thanks for the help

Comment: What I would do would be : 1) start with fixed positioning (`position:fixed;`) on the movable divs, so that I can move them independently. 2) catch the `mousewheel` event and recompute the positions of the divs (or the displacement if it's enough for you). 3) use `mydiv.css('top':mydistancetotopofwindow)` to reposition the elements. An alternative would be, still with fixed positionning, to call `animate({top:dy+'px})` in the mousewheel event handler. I hope you'll manage to decipher what I mean...

Comment: so basically catch the mousewheel and do the scrolling manually. might do that but not exactly now since there are more pressing matters.

Comment: Wait a minute, I'll try to make a fiddle, it will be clearer !

Comment: OK, that's very strange and kind of disturbing but probably a good start for what you want : http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/nQnJH/

Comment: yeah there's some strange things happening but i get the gist of it, will probably implement sometime in the future. thanks again.